# Number format in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

i have created table in oracle. one column is as follow:

- **GUID**  **NUMBER(16)**,

But value of this cloumn is shown   1,01000037073356E15

how can i correct it?

Comment: What correction do you want ?

Comment: like this 1010000372850390

Comment: But which tool are you using to display the number?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400393/toad-truncating-rounding-large-oracle-numbers or this http://bytes.com/topic/oracle/answers/64419-show-long-number-toad-7-5-2-0-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred storage data type for GUID values on Oracle is RAW(16).

A GUID is not a number in the sense that your height is a number -- you are not going to add them together, or take their average, for example.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions175.htm

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:77564387253035